# Why does range.location == NSNotFound mean that a word is found and not the opposite?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, spell-checking, nsrange

In this question ([iPhone objective-c: detecting a 'real' word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861161/iphone-objective-c-detecting-a-real-word/6861260#6861260)) the function returns the following line as true if the word is a 'real word'

```
return misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound;
```

I'm confused as to why this is "==" and not "!=". Wouldn't it make sense that "not equal to NSNotFound" would mean that the word was found -- as seems to be the case in this answer [Can NSRange determine if a snippet of text exists in a larger string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715830/can-nsrange-determine-if-a-snippet-of-text-exists-in-a-larger-string) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, that function returns true if the given word does *not* contain a misspelled word, so

```
return misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound;
```

makes sense.